# Windows batch file reference to own directory

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

Suppose you have `C:\foo\foo.bat` which needs to refer to `C:\foo\foo.txt`. It may be run from a different directory, but needs to get `foo.txt` from its own directory, not the current directory.  Obviously this could be done by putting the full path `C:\foo\foo.txt` in `foo.bat`.

The twist is, it's not known at the time of writing the batch file, where it will end up residing on the user's machine, so what the batch file actually needs to do is *get foo.txt from the directory where I live, wherever that happens to be*. (In a C program I'd use `argv[0]` but that doesn't seem to work with batch files.)

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
%~dp0
```

Will give you the full path to the script.

```
%~f0
```

Will give you the full path to the script, including the script name.

Comment: If you're going to use the `shift` command though, you need to make sure that you cache that information somewhere (like a variable) before doing a `shift` or you'll lose your information.